# Convert time format to long variable in Java

Tags: java, converters, time-format

Is there a possibility to convert a time format which is represented as a string (00:00:000) to long variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by *Convert to currentTimeMillis() or some float variable.*, but if you are simply looking to convert the given time to `long` then you can do something like this using simple split:

```
String timeString = "01:00:100";
int multiplier[] = {3600000, 60000, 100};
String splits[] = timeString.split(":");
long time = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < splits.length; x++) {
    time += (Integer.parseInt(splits[x]) * multiplier[x]);
}
System.out.println(time);
```

Here, the time is being represented in `Milliseconds`.

Also, this is plain `Java` and nothing `Android` specific.

Comment: @fox I'm glad it worked for you. Have a nice day ahead. :)

Answer (score 2):

That simply doesn't make much sense.

[currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) returns *the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.*

In other words: the result of a call to that method represents a full blown time stamp; not only hh::mm:sss as in your example; but all of that plus year, month, ...

Thus the answer here: you should step back and clarify for yourself what your actual requirements are.